# Momentjs how to convert a time string correctly to time offset since "utc start of current day"

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

Well I have a time string like "06:00:00+00" and "06:00:00+01" and I wish to convert those to a literal to show the current offset to "utc zero".

The code I tried:

```
const v="06:00:00+00"
const fmt = "hh:mm:ss Z"
const m = moment(v, fmt).diff(moment(v, fmt).startOf('day'));
console.log(m);
console.log(m/(3600*1000));
```

However this logs "8 hours". - as if it uses my local timezone. - Trying to remove the time zone parameter `fmt = "hh:mm:ss"` makes it just ignore the time zone.

So how can I achieve this? (And yes this would mean the integer could be negative, if utc is not yet in the specified date).

Comment: what if there is a date change while adjusting?

Comment: @AyushGupta what do you mean? As I said, if for example I'm at utc-11 and the current time there is "01:00:00-11" I expect `-10*3600*1000` as result.

Comment: moment().utc(v, fmt).diff(moment().utc(v, fmt).startOf('day'));

Comment: @Ashok testing with `v=06:00:00+1` shows "6" for last log, while i expect "5".

Comment: v=06:00:00+1 is not a right timezone it should be v=06:00:00+01 or v=06:00:00+01.00 Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

A solution with core JS to compare to UTC:

```js
function getTimeDiff(timeString) {
  let curDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  return (new Date(`${curDate}T${timeString}00`).getTime() - new Date(`${curDate}T00:00:00Z`).getTime())/(3600 * 1000);
}

console.log(getTimeDiff("06:00:00+01"));
console.log(getTimeDiff("06:00:00-07"));
console.log(getTimeDiff("20:00:00-07"));
```

Comment: While it is neat to use core JS, there are a lot of troubling points in reinventing the wheel. For example the above doesn't work with timezones that don't have an integer offset. (IE: +05:30 for India). And then there are the special indicators like `Z`; for this reason I think using a library is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution use utc() from moment()

```
const v="06:00:00+00"
const fmt = "hh:mm:ss Z"
const m = moment(v, fmt).diff(moment().utc(v, fmt).startOf('day'));
console.log(m/(3600*1000)); -> 6
```

With time zone

```
// Here is time zone +01.00 
const v="06:00:00+01.00"
console.log(m/(3600*1000)); -> 5

// Here is time zone -01.00 
const v="06:00:00-01.00"
console.log(m/(3600*1000)); -> 7
```

for country-based like UTC+08:45 you need to take care of denominator.

Comment: @paul23 Please update your moment version form 2.2.1 to ^2.24.0 and let me know. Thanks